# Push upgrade stuck in "Scheduled" status

Tags: managed-package, push-upgrade

A push upgrade of our managed package was scheduled for two days ago for 7 Orgs. 6 of these completed as either `Succeeded` or `Failed`. One is still marked as `Scheduled` and the 7 collectively are at a status of `In Progress (6 of 7 completed)`. The Org which is at status `Scheduled` still has the package installed at the old version and seems to be functioning correctly.

Has anyone seen this before or knows the cause?

Is it safe to abort the batch and try again for that Org, and will the Successful upgrades be unaffected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We opened a case with Salesforce about this issue. They were not able to explain what had caused it but said it happens at times.

They recommendeded clicking through to the job details for that org and aborting the upgrade for that org (so not aborting the overall job for the batch of 7 but aborting for that org specifically). They recommended then rescheduling the job and that it should work as expected.

This worked successfully for us - we aborted for the 1 org, scheduled another push upgrade and it ran successfully.